# Safely creating a C# distributable reference?

Tags: c#, reference

I was wondering if it was possible to compile my C# project in such a way that it can be included in a class library project as a reference, but that it's impossible to reverse engineer my application if I distribute it, like keeping all the functions and fields but without any function code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an "Obfuscator". There are a couple of it, some free, some not, with more or less features. For example, there's a community edition of Dotfuscator with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to remove all the function code because without it, there would be nothing to run!

By default the C# compiler will produce IL code (the high level "assembly language" of .Net) which includes method and property names, parameter names and so on, which makes it very easy for tools such as `Reflector` to reverse engineer the code back to C#.

However, tools known as "obfuscators" are available. These take your program and change all the names to single letters, and reorganise the code (without changing its meaning) to make it much harder to reverse engineer.

The most common of these is `Dotfuscator`, a free version of which comes with Visual Studio.

Here's a Microsoft article about obfuscation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164058.aspx

Here's a short list of obfuscators: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET